# Not all components see the same state sequence?

Tags: redux, react-redux

See the example code:
https://codesandbox.io/s/G5A04RB23

State is simple, contains only a single `value`. Both `Sub` and `App` is connected to redux. When click the dispatch button, `value` incremented. And `App` will clear the state in `componentWillReceiveProps` when the value reaches `3`.

But from the console log, it appears `Sub` never sees the `3` state.

`VM220:80 action
VM220:21 reducer
VM220:83 dispatch: 0.525146484375ms
VM220:52 app prop 1
VM220:58 app render 1
VM220:32 sub prop 1
VM220:35 sub render 1
VM220:80 action
VM220:21 reducer
VM220:83 dispatch: 0.485107421875ms
VM220:52 app prop 2
VM220:58 app render 2
VM220:32 sub prop 2
VM220:35 sub render 2
VM220:80 action
VM220:21 reducer
VM220:83 dispatch: 0.4931640625ms
VM220:52 app prop 3 <<< app see 3
VM220:58 app render 3

VM220:32 sub prop 0 <<< sub never see 3
VM220:35 sub render 0
VM220:52 app prop 0
VM220:58 app render 0`

I thought with redux, state should be consistent to all the components and every component should see the same state all the time. Is this the expected behavior or what am I doing wrong here?

**EDIT1**

Also tried with raw redux (instead of react-redux): https://codesandbox.io/s/Jq6gBoGzK

This time we do see both `app` and `sub` see the state `value=3`

So it appears to be a `react-redux` behavior. But it's a bit surprising behavior to me, I still expect all the components **see** every state change (thus props change). See my graph below:

Expect:

`state1 -> (update props of comp1 ... compN) -> state2`

Actual:

`state1 -> (update props of comp1) -> state2 -> (update props of comp2)`

Any reason why react-redux doing this instead of my expecting?

`sub listener 1
app listener 1
sub listener 2
app listener 2
sub listener 3
app listener 3
sub listener 0
app listener 0`

Answer (score 0):

Here's what's happening behind the scenes when you're rendering your app:

1. Get props from Redux for the `App` component
2. Call `App::componentWillReceiveProps()` with props from step #1
3. Call `App::render()` with props from step #1
4. `App::render()` tells React to render the `Sub` component
5. Get props from Redux for the `Sub` component
6. Call `Sub::componentWillReceiveProps()` with props from step #5
7. Call `Sub::render()` with props from step #5

When you dispatch the `clearAction()` event in `App::componetWillReceiveProps()` (between steps #2 and #3), Redux immediately changes the `value` property in the store from `3` to `0`, so by the time you get to step #5, the Redux store contains `value=0`, which is why it appears that the `Sub` component never sees the `value=3`.

You can see this by tweaking your code and calling `store.dispatch(clearAction());` after a timeout:

```
if (nextProps.value == 3) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    store.dispatch(clearAction());
  }, 1000); // dispatch the clearAction() after one second
}
```

With that change you should see the `value=3` render all the way down to the `Sub` component, and then automatically change to `value=0` one second after your click when the `clearAction()` event gets dispatched.

Comment: Thanks. Just added some comparison code without using react-redux. Still trying to understand why it behaves like this. I don't see any document describing this either. Am I writing code in a bad way that is not supposed to be?

Comment: Consider your `App` component: if in the `render()` method you decided to render the `Sub` component if the value property was `1`, but render the `DifferentSub` component if the value property was `2`, it doesn't make sense for React to compute the properties for `Sub` if it never gets rendered, and it doesn't know if it's going to be rendered until `App::render()` gets called. This is why the properties for each component aren't computed until right before they're rendered.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with how you're writing code. Why is it important that the `Sub` component receive the `value=3` prop if it's going to immediately receive the `value=0` prop right after?